# How to extract first value from each array-like element in column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column with single elements as well as array-like elements but I don't think it looks like an array:

[image]

I need to extract first value from this array-like element. First, I check if it's array. If so I extract first elemnt, if not I return default value. I use this function:

```
def get_top_element(x):
    if isinstance(x, np.ndarray):
        return x[0]
    return x

df_no_outliers['brand'] = df_no_outliers['brand'].apply(get_top_element)
```

Following error araises:

> IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

How can I make it work?

**EDIT:**

If I convert column to tuple then I get this:

```
tpl=tuple(df_no_outliers['brand'])
tpl
```

[image]

Comment: "First, I check if it's array. If so I extract first elemnt, if not I return default value." What do you think should be the result, if it's an *empty* array?

Comment: It's certainly not `np.ndarray` as they would print `array([...])`. They may be lists or strings that look like lists. what do you get when you print `df.tail(5).to_dict()`?

Comment: `df['Bluesky'].str[0]`

Comment: @mozway `.str[0]` certainly doesn't give the expected answer for the case `return x`.

Comment: @Quang `pd.Series(['a', ['b', 'c']]).str[0]` gives `pd.Series(['a', 'b'])`, no? Sure it doesn't check specifically for a numpy array, but this might not be needed.

Comment: what would it give for `pd.Series(['ab','abc'])`? I'd think OP expects the same series back.

Comment: Fair point, but in this case slicing wouldn't be needed. Feel free to reopen if you want. OP can always use `return x[0] if len(x)>0 else x` to fix the error.

Comment: I don't know what's the elemnt type. If it's list  or string or what. It looks trange and I can't slice it.

Comment: @mozway it doesn't solve the issue. It returns the first character only from each element

Comment: I edited my question and added code and result of converting column to `tuple`. It shows that `[...]` is an array. At least I think so

Comment: Have you tested `return x[0] if len(x)>0 else x`?

Comment: The error is because, somewhere you might have had an empty numpy array `np.array([])`.

Comment: @mozway I answered you before, it returns only the very first character from the element

Comment: Then your "strings" are instances of `np.ndarray`? Please provide a reproducible input.

Comment: Given the code and sample data in the OP, this issue is not reproducible: [see code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVvHV.png)

Comment: @mustafa00, `if isinstance(x, np.ndarray) and x.size>0 :` should solve your *problem*.

Comment: @Timeless it works! Thanks a lot:) I wonder why `x.size` solves the problem?

Comment: You're welcome ;). The error you were getting was triggered by the indexing `[0]` of the first empty *NumPy*'s array (*i.e* `np.array([])`) hold by the column `"brand"`. So by adding `x.size>0`, you'll bypass those empty arrays (*i.e avoid indexing*) because [`size`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.size.html) returns the number of elements in an *NumPy*'s array.